# onClick listener not firing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple todo app in react and am at the point where I am trying to delete items. So I have created a `removeTodo` method in my App.js file.
I have a todoList component which loops through the `todos`array in the state.todos and then injects the `todo`component. Although I am looking at a way in which I can pass the removeTodo function down to the todo component. Here is my attempt at doing this...

```
 removeTodo(){
//just need this function to fire
console.log("1234")
```

}

```
 render() {

return (
  <div className="App">

   <div className="header">
    <h1>Todo Application</h1>
   </div>

   <div className="header">
    <input
    type="text"
    ref={((ref) => this.input = ref)}
    value={this.state.todoText}
    onKeyPress={this.handleSub.bind(this)}
    />
   </div>
   <TodoList todos={this.state.todos} remove={this.removeTodo.bind(this)}/>
   //passing in removeTodo method to props       
  </div>
);
}
```

Here's my todoList Component

```
function todoList(props){

return (

<ul className="todoList">

{props.todos.map((todo, index) => {
    return(
    <Todo onClick={props.remove} name={todo.name} key={index}/>
    //the todo component just renders an li with the name inside the todos 
      array
    );
})}

</ul>

);

}
```

Whenever I go to click on the rendered Todo nothing happens, why is the onClick not firing? I'm new to react so sorry in advance for any ignorance

Comment: `onClick` will be like any other prop given to the `Todo` component, so you need to add `this.props.onClick` on a `onClick` prop on an element in `Todo` as well.

Comment: I kinda get you although could you provide an example? I'll upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClick` will be like any other prop given to the `Todo` component, so you need to add the `onClick` function in the props to a `onClick` prop on an element in `Todo` as well.

**Example**

```js
function TodoList(props) {
  return (
    <ul className="todoList">
      {props.todos.map((todo, index) => (
        <Todo
          onClick={() => console.log(`Clicked ${index}!`)}
          name={todo.name}
          key={index}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function Todo(props) {
  return <li onClick={props.onClick}>{props.name}</li>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoList todos={[{ name: "foo" }, { name: "bar" }]} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Great, this is perfect! Thanks